# How to inject `apollo client` through react context via `contextType` instead of consumer?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I am looking for `contextType` way to inject `apollo client` to a react component. I know below code works but it requires a few lines of code.

```
import { ApolloConsumer } from "react-apollo";

const WithApolloClient = () => (
  <ApolloConsumer>
    {client => "We have access to the client!" /* do stuff here */}
  </ApolloConsumer>
);
```

React doc(https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context) introducers a new way to inject context without using `consumer`. It is done by set `contextType` for the component class. I wonder how I can use `contextType` to inject `apollo client`? What `contextType` should I use?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found I can import `ApolloContext` from `react-apollo` to solve it like below:

```
import { ApolloContext } from 'react-apollo';

const HomeContainer = (props: HomeProps) => {
  const context = useContext(ApolloContext);
  return <Home {...props} />;
}
```